# Why is ffmpeg lossless trimming reducing my bitrate

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm trying to do a lossless trim of a video to remove a section from the start. I'm running the following command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -noaccurate_seek -ss 00:02:54.6 -i myinput.ts -c copy -map 0 myoutput.ts
```

The quality looks lossless to me but I notice the bitrate has been reduced from 9548kbps to 9105kbps. I was wondering why this was happening as I thought ffmpeg wasn't doing any re-encoding on this video. And does this mean that this is not actually a lossless cut?

Comment: Unless your input is constant bitrate, there will be variance in bitrate across the  stream. ffmpeg is showing the you the average bitrate of the trimmed portion.

Comment: Actually, both the bitrate values I mentioned came from viewing the file details in the Windows 10 File Explorer